# Doctrine ManyToOne Relation not finding data with findBy method

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a Article table that is allowed to have many comments.

And when i use findBy it does not find anything for that Article.

Here is my show Action.

```
$comments = $commentRepository->findBy(['article' => $article]);    
dump($comments);die;
```

which just outputs-.

```
ArticleController.php on line 52:
[]
```

When i do findAll however i get 20 Results which look like this

```
$allComments = $commentRepository->findAll();
dump($allComments);die;

  0 => Comment^ {#881 ▼
-id: 1
-authorName: "Author name here"
-content: "Here is the comment content"
-article: Article^ {#809 ▼
  +__isInitialized__: false
  -id: 117
  -title: null
  -slug: null
  -content: null
  -publishedAt: null
  -author: null
  -heartCount: 0
  -imageFilename: null
  -createdAt: null
  -updatedAt: null
  -comments: null
   …2
}
```

Here is the complete showAction method

```
/**
 * @Route("/news/{article}",
 *      name="article_show")
 *
 * @param Article $article
 * @param SlackClient $slack
 * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
 * @param CommentRepository $commentRepository
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 * @throws \Http\Client\Exception
 * @throws \Nexy\Slack\Exception\SlackApiException
 */
public function show( $article,
                     SlackClient $slack,
                     EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
                     CommentRepository $commentRepository

)
{

    $allComments = $commentRepository->findAll();

    $comments = $commentRepository->findBy(['article' => $article]);
    dump($allComments);die;

    $repository = $entityManager->getRepository(Article::class);


    /**
     * @var Article $article
     */
    $articleResult = $repository->findOneBy(['slug' => $article]);
    if (!$articleResult) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('No ' . $article . ' found');
    }
```

Not sure if needed but here is my Article and Comment Entitiy just to make sure i have verything here.

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ArticleRepository")
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"title"})
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, unique=true)
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $publishedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $heartCount = 0;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $imageFilename;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Comment", mappedBy="article")
     */
    private $comments;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSlug(): ?string
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }

    public function setSlug(string $slug): self
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getContent(): ?string
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public function setContent(?string $content): self
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPublishedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->publishedAt;
    }

    public function setPublishedAt(?\DateTimeInterface $publishedAt): self
    {
        $this->publishedAt = $publishedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAuthor(): ?string
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

    public function setAuthor(string $author): self
    {
        $this->author = $author;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getHeartCount(): ?int
    {
        return $this->heartCount;
    }

    public function setHeartCount(int $heartCount): self
    {
        $this->heartCount = $heartCount;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getImageFilename(): ?string
    {
        return $this->imageFilename;
    }

    public function setImageFilename(?string $imageFilename): self
    {
        $this->imageFilename = $imageFilename;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $createdAt): self
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $updatedAt): self
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Comment[]
     */
    public function getComments(): Collection
    {
        return $this->comments;
    }

    public function addComment(Comment $comment): self
    {
        if (!$this->comments->contains($comment)) {
            $this->comments[] = $comment;
            $comment->setArticle($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeComment(Comment $comment): self
    {
        if ($this->comments->contains($comment)) {
            $this->comments->removeElement($comment);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($comment->getArticle() === $this) {
                $comment->setArticle(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

and the Comments Entitiy.

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CommentRepository")
 */
class Comment
{

    use TimestampableEntity;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $authorName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Article", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $article;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getAuthorName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->authorName;
    }

    public function setAuthorName(string $authorName): self
    {
        $this->authorName = $authorName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getContent(): ?string
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public function setContent(string $content): self
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getArticle(): ?article
    {
        return $this->article;
    }

    public function setArticle(?article $article): self
    {
        $this->article = $article;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you need any other information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in `showAction` method.

You want to take a look at `$article` argument. Phpdoc says it will be instance of `Article` but it won't be.

Here:

```
$articleResult = $repository->findOneBy(['slug' => $article]);
```

You assume that `$article` contains string representing slug.

So you search for comments by article slug and comments don't contain this information. You want to fetch them by article id.

Comment: Hey thank you a lot. The issuse was using the wrong (or no) slug to fetch the data. Thank you.  ```$comments = $commentRepository->findBy(['article' => $articleResult]);
```